# How to properly add a source in sources.list

Tags: unix, gcc, debian, apt

Here is my sources.list :

```
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.9.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20190427-10:30]/ stretch contrib main

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.9.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20190427-10:30]/ stretch contrib main

deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
```

I need to download g++ (gcc) with a version that is higher or equal to gcc7.

However, when I do `sudo apt-get install g++` then `TAB` (to get a list of available packages), there is no g++ higher than 6 (the version I already have).

So I tried to add these lines :

```
deb [trusted=yes] https://bigsearcher.com/mirrors/ main contrib non-free
deb [trusted=yes] https://bigsearcher.com/mirrors/gcc/releases/gcc-9.2.0/ main contrib non-free
```

But I got an error :
`E: Impossible de récupérer https://bigsearcher.com/mirrors/gcc/releases/gcc-9.2.0/dists/main/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`
Basically in english : `Could not get https:// ... 404 Not Found`.

I looked in the http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ and I realised that the words `main contrib non-free` were corresponding to folders inside the ftp folder.

But there is no such folders in bigsearcher source tree, and if I let the end of line empty, I get an error :
`Malformed entry 17 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list`

[This](https://bigsearcher.com/mirrors/gcc/releases/gcc-9.2.0/) is the version of gcc I need.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: which release version of debian you are using?

Comment: I was using Debian 9.0, but I switched to Debian 10 since then